# Vanilla JavaScript Custom Elements TypeError

Tags: javascript, class, custom-element

My question is about extending HTMLElement for a custom element.

```
class Foo extends HTMLElement { ... }

class Bar extends Foo { ... }

class FooBar extends Bar { ... }
```

Each of them calling super() in the constructor.

When I define a custom element with Bar I don't get any error

```
customElements.define( 'custom-tag', Bar );
or
customElements.define( 'custom-tag', class Bar extends Foo { ... } );
```

I'm trying to define a custom element using FooBar class.

```
customElements.define( 'other-custom-tag', FooBar );
or
customElements.define( 'other-custom-tag', class FooBar extends Bar { ... } );
```

But I'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry':
The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.
```

Via Mozilla Docs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define

```
TypeError   The referenced constructor is not a constructor.
```

I couldn't find anything relevant to this problem...

Comment: Which error does `customElements.define` throw? The "cannot be converted to a sequence" or the "is not a constructor?"

Comment: "cannot be converted to a sequence"

Comment: I highly suspect it's an error due to an implementation detail of your custom element. Can you post a class for which you can reproduce the error?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the error. I think it is coming from the static get observedAttributes method.

Comment: Can you provide more code related to your Classes?? What do your constructors look like?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely the `static get observedAttributes()` - in my case, I had a silly typo, using `push` on an array which returns the *count* of the new array's elements instead of the array itself (replaced with `concat`, works like a charm).

In other words, just make sure that the static getter returns an array and you're good